# Calling external function from a class function

Tags: library

I'll try to explain my need:

1. I have a generic library I created, called `myIOT.h`.
2. This class have a pre-configured  MQTT and wifi setup.
3. Inside this library there is a `mqtt_callback` function, for all generic commands, such as `boot_time` and `connection_status`.
4. BUT, this library serves in several of my iot device's code, that each one has a few more mqtt commands, that is tailored just for s specific device, and I looking for a way that `iot.mqtt_callback(ext_mqtt_func)` will get as parameter a local ( which belong to the sketch and not to the library ), that will have the additional code needed.

I'll try to explain more clearly:

```
void myIOT::mqtt_callback(ext_mqtt_func){
if (a == true ) {
do something

};

else {

ext_mqtt_func()); // calling another fucntion that belongs to sketch and not library

}
```

Comment: Note that it is better to use if (a) than comparing a boolean with true or false. If you name a better so it is clear it is a boolean it is better maintainable.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers it is a string compare function to set a MQTT comman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

You pass function pointer as function parameter.

See this stackoverflow question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582161/c-function-pointer-as-parameter

Comment: thank you, it works great. Since it have to a string using a MQTT, this ext_fuct needs as well to pass this string - and the explanation above is for a no-arg function, so I did upgrade it to be  `typedef void (*cb_func)(char msg1[50])` that passes its string ( and it works great ), but I would rather pass it as a pointer to that string ( which fails )